# MongoDB database architecture

Tags: mongodb, architecture, database-design

I want to understand more about the system and DB architecture of MongoDB.

I am trying to understand how MongoDB stores and retrieves the documents. If it's all in memory etc.

A comparative analysis between MongoDB and Oracle will be a bonus but, I am mostly focusing on understanding the MongoDB architecture per se.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I can't claim to be an expert, but it most certainly does write to disk (not sure when / how often / whether it always flushes / whether you can explicitly flush). In fact, it snatches quite a bit of space (likely to do its indexing i'm guessing)

Comment: As a general, really over-arching comparison, the greatest arguments I've heard between it and a traditional relational db (like Oracle or MS SQL Server or MySQL) is one of transactionality/reliability vs extreme scale. If you wouldn't lose sleep at night if some of your data got trashed, NoSQL options like Mongo are very performant and can scale to a *lot* of concurrent users. If you *need* guarantees on your data though, for now you're probably better off sticking to transactional dbs.

Comment: This question may be a little broader than the guidelines for questions on SO stipulate. I recommend that you go to the mongodb docs and read the material they provide. Of particular interest will be:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Architecture+and+Components,
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart,
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes

I hope this helps.

Comment: @marr75 I have already looked at the documents that you mentioned. Sadly they do not provide the details I am looking for. For example I can find many documents that talk about the file and storage structure of oracle Database. That is what I am looking at. What I do not understand is why posts like these are downvoted.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I did vote that it was too broad for SO. It's kind of a self-cleaning mechanism. SO questions are supposed to be quickly, permanently, and definitively answered (that's the goal anyway) and with broad topics, it's hard to do any of those 3. I know less than nothing about the architecture of an oracle database so it might not occur to me to point out that in mongo, documents within a collection are stored in incrementally growing files with a postfix number alongside a namespace file. (This is unique enough to a document database for me to identify in this case).

Comment: If you posted a question that was, "How are mongo collections stored in the filesystem? If you can make specific comparisons to an oracle database, please do so." The question would probably not be closed (or would already exist). Does this help at all?

Comment: @marr75 sure I will be more careful next time. Actually I had no way of putting this in a more specific manner. I was trying to find references to architecture of Mongo DB after I did my research and tried my luck in Google. Appreciate your help to keep SO clean. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Ayusman not a big deal, check out my last comment on gregor's answer for some great links I found that might help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MongoDB memory maps the database files. It allows the OS to control this and allocate the maximum amount of RAM to the memory mapping. As MongoDB updates and reads from the DB it is reading and writing to RAM. All indexes on the documents in the database are held in RAM also. The files in RAM are flushed to disk every 60 seconds. To prevent data loss in the event of power failure, the default is to run with journaling switched on. The journal file is flushed to disk every 100ms and if there is power loss is used to bring the database back to a consistent state. 
An important design decision with mongo is on the amount of RAM. You need to figure out your working set size - i.e if you are going to be reading and writing to only the most recent 10% of your data in the database then this 10% is your working set and should be held in memory for maximum performance. So if your working set is 10GB you are going to neen 10GB for max performance - otherwise your queries/updates will run slower as pages of memory are paged from disk into memory. 
Other important aspects of mongoDB are replication for backups and sharding for scaling. 
There are a lot of great online resources for learning.  MongoDB is free and opensource.

EDIT: 
It's a good idea to check out the tutorial 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial
and manual 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Manual
and the Admin Zone is useful too
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+Zone
and if you get bored of reading then the presentations are worth checking out. 
http://www.10gen.com/presentations

Comment: thanks for the info. I am actually looking for information on the line of your answer. It will be great to get similar details. Can you point me to any online resource that has the MongoDB internal desgin/architecture etc?

Comment: replication for read/query scaling as well (not just backups).

Comment: Do you think this answers your question or do you need more help?

Comment: @gregor yes I need some specific info, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching - Actually has nothing to do with cache, has to do with how mongo handles memory, some memory overhead, etc.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+Internals - Internals of Journals (Durability)

http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/inside-mongodb-the-internals-of-an-opensource-database - Best overview of internals I've found so far